# Transposition of Composition is Reversed Composition of Transpositions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm trying to show that $(UT)^*=T^*U^*$.

Here is my effort:

Consider the following data:

\begin{array}{lcl}
T:V\rightarrow W & \leadsto & T^*:W^*\rightarrow V^* \\
U:W\rightarrow Z & \leadsto & U^*:Z^*\rightarrow W^* \\
UT:V\rightarrow Z & \leadsto & \color{red}{(UT)^*:Z^*\rightarrow V^*} \\ \\
 & \Downarrow & \\
\\
V\overset{T}{\rightarrow} W & & \color{red}{Z^*}\overset{U^*}{\rightarrow}W^* \\
{\tiny{UT}}\searrow~\downarrow {\tiny{U}}& & \color{red}{{\tiny{T^*U^*}}\searrow}~\downarrow {\tiny{T^*}} \\
~~~~~~~~~~Z & & ~~~~~~~~~~~~\color{red}{V^*}
\end{array}

Note:

\begin{array}{rcl}
V^*&=&\{\varphi_V:V\rightarrow F, \text{$\varphi_V$ linear}\} \\ \\
W^*&=&\{\varphi_W:W\rightarrow F, \text{$\varphi_W$ linear}\} \\ \\
Z^*&=&\{\varphi_Z:Z\rightarrow F, \text{$\varphi_Z$ linear}\}
\end{array}

Thus, we have that

\begin{eqnarray}
(UT)^*(h)=h(UT),~h\in Z^*
\end{eqnarray}

by the definition of dual map (tranpsose) and

\begin{eqnarray}
h(UT)=(hU)T
\end{eqnarray}

by the associativity of transformations. Now, $hU$ is characterized by the map

\begin{eqnarray}
W\overset{U}{\rightarrow}Z~~ \\
{\tiny{hU}}\searrow~\downarrow {\tiny{h}} \\
F~~,
\end{eqnarray}

---

so $hU\in W^*$, and it is clear then that

\begin{eqnarray}
(hU)T=T^*(hU),
\end{eqnarray}

but $hU=U^*h$, or simply $U^{*}$, because $h$ itself is an element of $Z^*$ for which $U^*$ maps to $W^*$.

---

Hence, $(UT)^*=T^*U^*$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: This seems reasonable and very well thought at at first glance, save for the $W^*$ instead of $V^*$ in your first red text.

Comment: AH, yes! Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware that you can use AMScd to draw commutative diagrams? See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9401.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'll check that out. Thank you, joriki.

Comment: @joriki What about MiKTeX?

Comment: $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T @>>pita>P\\
@VcoffeeVV @VVteaV\\
R @>fantastic>> Q
\end{CD} Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Barisa: I don't know -- I just happened to see that post with the commutative diagrams shortly before I saw yours.